# Is there a simpler way to access the member function GetJ() in the example below?

Tags: c++, c++11, derived-class, unique-ptr

Is there a simpler way to access the member function `GetJ()` in the `Derived` class, other than the one chosen in the second `std::cout` below ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Base
{
    int i;

    public:

    Base(int k) : i(k) {}
    int GetI() { return i; }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
    int j;

    public:
    Derived(int u) : Base(10) { j = u; }
    int GetJ() { return j; }    
};

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Base> uptr(new Derived(5));
    std::cout << uptr->GetI() << std::endl;
    std::cout << static_cast<Derived*>(uptr.get())->GetJ() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: By the way, a simple `static_cast` [works just as fine](http://ideone.com/txJxm).

Comment: @chris: That is, as long as you *definitly* know that the base pointer points to that specific derived class.

Comment: @Xeo, Yes, but even if you don't, `reinterpret_cast` isn't your best choice.

Comment: @chris: OMG, I read that as `dynamic_cast`... oh my.

Answer (score 0):

## To the previous version of question:

First of all, `reinterpret_cast` is *definitely* wrong way to do this. Just try this:

```
struct A
{
    char x[10]; 
    A():x{9}{}

};

class Derived : public A, public Base
{
// your code here   
};
```

instead of your `Derived` definition.

`static_cast` works fine here.

## To the current state:

But *usually* when you are going to use `Derived` functionality by pointer to `Base` class, you want virtual function:

```
class Base
{
    //....
    virtual int GetJ() const = 0;
    // or virtual int GetJ() const { return -1;} if Base should be created itself.

    virtual ~Base(){} //oh, and don't forget virtual destructor!
};

class Derived: public Base
{
    //...
    virtual int GetJ() const { return j; }
}
```

Comment: From your example, it looks like you could do with a pure virtual function in the base class.

Comment: @chris It works with `GetJ()` as a pure virtual function in `Base`, i.e., if I replace the 2nd `std::cout` with `std::cout << uptr->GetJ() << std:;endl;` I get 5 printed ! If you submit an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe GetI and GetJ belongs to two different classes although `Derived` is derived from `Base`. Now the question relies how to access this.

```
Derived* p = new Derived(5));
std::cout << p->GetI() << std::endl;
std::cout << p->GetJ() << std::endl;
```

The above code should work well because you've derived from the places.

But if you really wanted to work with

```
Derived* p = new Derived(5));
Base* pBase  = p;
std::cout << pBase->GetI() << std::endl;
std::cout << p->GetJ() << std::endl;
```

The above approaches are just because the functions are not `virtual`. But if you declare the functions as virtual you really don't have to bother about upcasting and downcasting. the base pointer itself is sufficient to work for you